# SingleValuedAssociationField expected - Doctrine query builder

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity, one-to-many, query-builder, symfony-3.4

I want to return my holders of a card with query builder and OneToMany relationship.

I have a problem with Semantical Error:

> Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

```
return $this->getCardRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->leftJoin('Entity\CardHolder', 'ch', 'c.id = ch.id')
        ->where('ch.cards = :cards')
        ->setParameter('cardHolder', '%'.$card.'%')
        ->orderBy('ch.id', 'desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

And in my entities:

```
class Card 
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="LaunchPad\Base\Entity\Card\CardHolder",)
     * @JoinColumn(name="holder_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cardHolder;
}
```

And second entity:

```
class CardHolder
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->cards = new ArrayCollection();
   }

  /**
   * @var
   *
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Card", mappedBy="cardHolder")
   */
   protected $cards;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need both `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` for a bi-directional relationship. As you have it: CardHolder maps to Card, but not vice versa. Make sure to update your DB after that change, then try your QB again :)

Comment: As an aside, do I spot correctly that a Card does not need a CardHolder? `@JoinColumn(name="holder_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)` Hope those are not credit cards ;)

Comment: That did it. Thanks. :) @rkeet